# Attempting to fill up a reload bar using fillAmount when a button is pressed

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to have an icon fill up while you wait betwen firing shells (a reload kind of).
Here is my code :

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

public Image fillImg1;
public Image fillImg2;
float timeAmt1 = 1;
float time1;
float timeAmt2 = 1;
float time2 = 0;

void Start() { 
    time1 = timeAmt1;
    time2 = timeAmt2;
}

public void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        if (fillImg2 != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Got to P2 Reload");
            time2 = 0;
            while (time2 < timeAmt2)
            {
                Debug.Log("TEST");
                time2 += Time.deltaTime;
                fillImg2.fillAmount = time2;
            }

            Debug.Log("TEST COMPLETE");
        }
        else { Debug.Log("Fill Image 2 is null"); }
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        if (fillImg2 != null)
        {
            time2 = 0;
            Debug.Log("Got to P1 Reload");
        while (time1 < timeAmt1)
        {
            time1 += Time.deltaTime;
            fillImg1.fillAmount = time1 / timeAmt1;
        }
        time1 = timeAmt1    ;
    }
    else { Debug.Log("Fill Image 1 is null"); }
}
}
}
```

The images and the fill works when I test it (i've tried just setting it straight to 0.5f to see if it would work and it did), but my problem is it is filling over time. When I hit the shoot key of either player what I want it to do is for it to go to zero and start filling back up over a second.

Update : Still don't have this solved, very confused. Also tried what i initially attempted which is

```
while (time2 < timeAmt2)
            {
                Debug.Log(time2/timeAmt2);
                time2 += Time.deltaTime;
                fillImg2.fillAmount = time2 / timeAmt2;
            }
```

And the value of the debug is printing corretly, showing a lot of values starting at 0 and making there way up til 1 and then finishing, however it still does not effect the image at all

**Update - Solution** - Hugo helped me solve this so i'll put my code from start to finish here for anyone who comes across this with the same problem

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

public Image fillImg1;
public Image fillImg2;
private float timeAmt1 = 1;
private float time1;
private float timeAmt2 = 1;
private float time2 = 0;
private float lastFiredTime1 = 0f;
private float lastFiredTime2 = 0f;

private bool doFill1;
private bool doFill2;
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && lastFiredTime1 + 1f <=         Time.time)
    {
        time1 = 0;
        doFill1 = true;
        lastFiredTime1 = Time.time;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && lastFiredTime2 + 1f <= Time.time)
    {
        time2 = 0;
        doFill2 = true;
        lastFiredTime2 = Time.time;
    }

    if (doFill1)
    {
        if (fillImg1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Got to P1 Reload");

            Debug.Log("TEST");
            time1 += Time.deltaTime;
            fillImg1.fillAmount = time1 / timeAmt1;

            if (fillImg1.fillAmount >= 1)
            {
                Debug.Log("TEST COMPLETE");
                doFill1 = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Fill Image 1 is null");
        }
    }

    if (doFill2)
    {
        if (fillImg2)
        {
            Debug.Log("Got to P2 Reload");

            Debug.Log("TEST");
            time2 += Time.deltaTime;
            fillImg2.fillAmount = time2 / timeAmt2;

            if (fillImg2.fillAmount >= 1)
            {
                Debug.Log("TEST COMPLETE");
                doFill2 = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Fill Image 2 is null");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Unity is completing everything in the while loop in a single frame which is why you see all the correct debug messages but don't see the image changing. I would suggest using an IEnumerator coroutine as a way of incrementing  time2 over a period of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted in the comments you `while` is a bad idea since the entire loop gets executed in **one single frame**.

Either use a `bool` flag and do your filling with each `Update` iteration like

```
private bool doFill2;
public void Update() 
{
    // Use the KeyDown only for initializing the counter
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        time2 = 0;
        // enable the counter via the flag
        doFill2 = true;
    }

    // Every frame check the flag
    if(doFill2)
    {
        if (fillImg2)
        {
            Debug.Log("Got to P2 Reload");

            // Only go one incremental step per frame!
            Debug.Log("TEST");
            time2 += Time.deltaTime;
            fillImg2.fillAmount = time2 / timeAmt2;

            // Check the fillAmount and if reached one reset the flag and stop the fill
            if(fillImg2.fillAmount >= 1)
            {
                Debug.Log("TEST COMPLETE");
                doFill2 = false;
            }
        }     
    }
    else 
    { 
        Debug.Log("Fill Image 2 is null"); 
    }

    // TODO: Do the equivalent for fill1
}
```

---

Or use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) - I would prefer this one! It is often easier to maintain and control.

```
// Still use the bool to avoid concurrent routines
bool doingFill2;

public void Update() 
{
    // On KeyDown start the routine - if it is not already running
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !doingFill2)
    {
        StartCoroutine (Fill2Routine());
    }

    // TODO: Do the equivalent for fill1
}

IEnumerator Fill2Routine ()
{
    // This should not happen but just in case ignore concurrent routine
    if(doingFill2) yield break; 

    // Initialize the value
    time2 = 0;
    fillImg2.fillAmount = 0;
    // Set the flag to block concurrent routines
    doingFill2 = true;

    if (!fillImg2)
    {
        Debug.Log("Fill Image 2 is null"); 
        yield break;
    }

    Debug.Log("Got to P2 Reload");

    while(fillImg2.fillAmount < 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("TEST");
        fillImg2.fillAmount = time2 / timeAmt2;

        // increment the time here so in the first frame the fill actually starts with 0
        time2 += Time.deltaTime;

        // Important! Tells Unity to pause the routine here,
        // render this frame and continue from here 
        // in the next frame.
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("TEST COMPLETE");

    // When done don't forget to give the flag free again
    doingFill2 = false;
} 

// TODO: Do the equivalent for fill1
```

Comment: Thanks! The Coroutine wouldn't work for me sadly but your initial solution worked perfectly! I also added a check to ensure that this amination would not reset half way through to ensure a full reload was shown and you werent able to restart it if you couldnt shoot. Ill put an update for anyone who wants to see your solution at a later stage. Thanks again Hugo!

Comment: I think I spottet why the routin probably didn't work: I forgot to also set `fillImg2.fillAmount = 0;` in the beginning ... so probably `fillImg2.fillAmount < 1` was never true so the filling skipped imeditately. Just edited

Comment: Yea I spotted that as well and tried but wasnt sure where to change the fill amount value to 0 to ensure it didnt keep flickering back between the current fill value and the 0 value.  I see what you mean now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I very strongly recommend you use [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for this kind of stuff.